# Parquet file with more than one schema

Tags: dataframe, parquet

I am used to parquet file with a single schema. I came across a file which, seemingly has more than one schema. I used pandas to convert it to a CSV file. The result is some things like this:

```
table-1,table-2,table-3
0, {data for table-1} {dat for table-2} {data for table-3}
```

I read the parquet file format and it looks like a single parquet file has a single schema.

Does parquet support more than one schema in a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Parquet format only supports a single schema per file. This schema is written into the footer of the file and accounts for all sections of the file. You could probably reread the CSV file into `pandas` and save that as a Parquet file, but ultimately you will be better off when you save each table as a separate file. The latter should also be much more performant and space-efficient.